# How can I run a void command outside the class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I am trying to run a void code (written inside of a class) when I start the program automatically.

```
void _configureAndConnect() {
    String _named  = null;
    String _topnamed = null;
    String osPrefix = 'Commander';
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      osPrefix = 'NotCommander';
    }
    if ( _name.isEmpty) {
      _named = _hostTextController.text;
    }else {_named = _name;}

    if ( _topname.isEmpty) {
      _topnamed = _topicTextController.text;
    }else {_topnamed = _topname;}
    manager = MQTTManager(
      //  _name.isEmpty ? host: _buildTextFieldWith.text, host: _buildTextFieldWith.text : _name,

        host: _named,

        topic: _topnamed,
        identifier: osPrefix,
        state: currentAppState);
    manager.initializeMQTTClient();
    manager.connect();
  }
```

This is my code inside of a class.
I want to run it when I open the app automatically.
Thank you.

Comment: do you run it on the homepage of your app ?

Comment: I have just a main.dart page where everything is on it.

Comment: put it at the same level as `main()` and call it inside `main();` before `runApp();`

Comment: what about `import` and inject

Comment: So you mean that I can put all the void code inside of the main() before runApp() ?